# I'm am trying to change a css property using $_GET getting wrong result

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

First of all this is a wordpress page so [insert_php] is a replacement for `<?php`.

The url of the page is as follows `http://********.com/?page_id=98#highlights?sel=q1s`

the code on the page is as follows

```
<div id="Question1" style="background-color:[insert_php] if ($_GET['sel'] == "q1s") { echo "black"; } else { echo "white"; }[/insert_php];">
```

this is my current code and it still showing no results, I checked the actual value I'm getting for background-color and for some reason am getting the result "white".

Comment: That query string does not look valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the second parameter `sel` passed in the URL should be directly appended to the first argument declared with the ampersand (`&`) identifier.

The use of the fragment identifier (`#`) in the middle of your arguments is misleading as he can also be used to declare arguments to the URL. If the hash mark is meant to identify an anchor, it is better to place it at the end for avoiding errors and better readability :

```
http://you-url.com/?page_id=98&sel=q1s#highlights
```

Comment: To add a bit of explanation: the "fragment" of a URL (everything after the first `#`) is not sent to the server running your PHP, it is only used by the browser after the page has been generated. The "query string" (from the first `?` up until that `#`) is what is processed by PHP as `$_GET`, with each parameter separated by `&`.

Answer (score -1):

Try something

```
<div id="Question1" style="background-color:[insert_php] if ($_GET['sel'] == "q1s") { echo "black"; } else { echo "white"; }[/insert_php];">
[insert_php] echo $_GET['sel'];[/insert_php]
</div>
```

and see what is in the $_GET